# How can i 1. get an id from a canvas 2. fix the canvas misplacement , in kivy with python

Tags: python, canvas, kivy

1. I'm trying to get the size of the rectangle from the canvas called Canvas_Widget class, but no matter what I do, it keeps on giving an error
   the code that I wrote and the description of the error are given in the code as a comment.

source file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.metrics import dp

Window.size= dp(500),dp(500)

class Canvas_Widget(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class MainWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def minimizer(self,button):
        button.background_color=(1,0,0,1)
        #here i  want to try and print the size of that rect id that i created
        # i tried "print(self.ids.Canvas.ids.rect.size)"
        """the error says: (((File "f:\canvas\1\main.py", line 16, in minimizer
            print(canvas.ids.rect.size)
            File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in  kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
            AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__')))"""
    def minimizer_release(self,button):
        button.background_color=(.3,.3,1,1) 

class mynewApp(App):
    pass

mynewApp().run()
```

here is the kivy file:

```
MainWidget:


<Canvas_Widget>:
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgb:.4,.4,.4,1
        Rectangle:
            id:rect     #this is the id that Im trying to share with the MainWidget
            pos:dp(100),dp(100)
            size:self.width - dp(200),self.height - dp(200)
        Color: 
            rgb:0,1,0,1
        Line:
            points:(dp(100),self.height - dp(100),self.width - dp(100),dp(100))
        Line:
            points:(dp(100),dp(100),self.width - dp(100),self.height - dp(100))

<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text:'press'
        on_press:root.minimizer(self)
        background_color:(.3,.3,1,1)   
        on_release: root.minimizer_release(self) 
    Canvas_Widget:
        id:Canvas
```

here is also the problem with the placement of the canvas on the screen. its suppose to be on the right side, but it's on the left side, on the button:
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NTjh.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twNzm.png)

by the way, I'm sorry to ask for too much. it's just that I really want to know how to fix this problem.
thanks

Comment: In `kvlang` [**`ids`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids) are supposed to be used with widgets not with graphical instructions.

Comment: If you want to access or modify the size of the (canvas) rectangle, try assigning it attrs. from outside using some kivy properties. Thereby you will have full control over it.

Comment: thanks, can you tell me how to fix the canvas problem as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to notice that in `kvlang` binding happens by `Builder` automatically (at least from developer's side). That's why it's convenient to use this language for design purpose. From kivy [doc.](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#concept-behind-the-language),

> As your application grows more complex, it’s common that the construction of widget trees and explicit declaration of bindings becomes verbose and hard to maintain. The KV Language is an attempt to overcome these shortcomings. The KV language, sometimes called kvlang or the kivy language, allows you to create your widget tree in a declarative way and to bind widget properties to each other or to callbacks in a natural manner.

Now in `kvlang` when you do something like this :

```py
Rectangle:
    pos:dp(100),dp(100)
```

in the canvas instructions, you are basically instructing to draw a rectangle at (100, 100) in the window. But what you want (as it seems) is to draw that rectangle where the widget is and shifted by (100, 100) from its position.

Now as you used `BoxLayout` as container, each of its child's position, size are managed by itself (if not provided explicitly). So to reflect that changes you need to change the above lines of code by the following,

```py
Rectangle:
    pos: self.x+dp(100), self.y+dp(100)
```

This will reposition the rectangle (automatically) whenever the position of widget (x, y) changes.

Thus the changes you need in your `kvlang` are,

```py
<Canvas_Widget>:
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgb:.4,.4,.4,1
        Rectangle:
#            id:rect # Will not work here.
#            pos:dp(100),dp(100)
            pos: self.x+dp(100), self.y+dp(100)
            size: self.width - dp(200), self.height - dp(200)
        Color: 
            rgb:0,1,0,1
        Line:
#            points:(dp(100),self.height - dp(100),self.width - dp(100),dp(100))
            points: (self.x+dp(100), self.y+self.height-dp(100), self.x+self.width-dp(100),self.y+dp(100))
        Line:
#            points:(dp(100),dp(100),self.width - dp(100),self.height - dp(100))
            points: (self.x+dp(100), self.y+dp(100),self.x+self.width-dp(100), self.y+self.height-dp(100
```

Comment: thank you so much, crystal clear explanation. and quite helpful.